# Necessary conditions for Ax=b to Have a Solution

Tags: linear-algebra

The necessary and sufficient conditions for $Ax=b, ~A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ to have a unique solution is that $\det(A)$ is nonzero. I am looking for a necessary condition for the existence of the solution, which is not (necessarily) sufficient? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: The necessary condition is that $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$. It's also sufficient.

Comment: I need a necassary condition which is not sufficient

Comment: Maybe $A \neq O$? That's definitely necessary.

Comment: A is not equal to $I$ maybe.

Comment: Do you mean a condition such that $Ax = b$ has a solution *for all* $b$?  Or, are we looking at a fixed $A$ and $b$ here?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a condition: if $A$ has a row of zeros, then $b$ must have a zero in the corresponding entry.

This is also true under row-reduction.  In particular, if $R$ is an invertible matrix, then $Rb$ must have a zero entry corresponding to any zero row of $RA$.

It is sufficient for the above to be true for *every* invertible matrix $R$.  It is also sufficient for the above to be true for the $R$ that puts $A$ in row-echelon form.